Find an order in which the 10 digits satisfy certain property
Let $d_1, d_2, ..., d_{10} \in \{ 0, 1, ..., 9\}$, where $d_i \neq d_j$ when $i \neq j$.
Find an order in which the following statement is true:
$d_1d_2 × d_3d_4d_5 = d_6d_7d_8d_9d_{10}$.
I know this can be solved, for instance, using python. But I won't give up, I want to come with a solution mathematically. Any ideas?
Some easy ideas I came up with:
$d_2 × d_5 \equiv d_{10} \pmod{10}$
$d_1d_2$ and $d_3d_4d_5$ divide $d_6d_7d_8d_9d_{10}$. Maybe I can use a divisibility rule if $d_1d_2$ is a relatively good number.
If $d_{10}$ is odd then $d_1$ and $d_3$ are also odd.
These are very trivial ideas, and seem to be quite useless. Any help will be appreciated!

A brute force program is mathematical.  Presumably you are looking for a solution in range of a pencil and paper calculation.  Do you have any reason to think such a thing exists?  There are only $30,240$ ways to choose the five digits on the left and you can then perform the multiplication to see if it works.  That is probably less work than computing over 700 digits of $\pi$, which was done by hand (though not all of them were correct, it was probably the same amount of work).

@RossMillikan I also question whether there is an analytical approach that would facilitate a pencil and paper calculation.  However, that doesn't mean that no such approach exists.  Further, from the perspective of the OP (i.e. original poster), who is presumably not a number theory expert, it is difficult to imagine that the OP would have a confident opinion, one way or another, on whether an analytical approach exists.  So, it seems to me that your question: "Do you have any reason to think such a thing exists?" is somewhat unfair.

Exactly, I'm just a student yet. And yes, I meant an analytical approach.

I wrote a program to brute force search through all possible combinations, and it found the following combinations (with leading zeros, trimmed):
$$
12 * 483 = 5796\\
18 * 297 = 5346\\
27 * 198 = 5346\\\
27 * 594 = 16038\\
28 * 157 = 4396\\
36 * 495 = 17820\\
39 * 186 = 7254\\
39 * 402 = 15678\\
42 * 138 = 5796\\
45 * 396 = 17820\\
46 * 715 = 32890\\
48 * 159 = 7632\\
52 * 367 = 19084\\
54 * 297 = 16038\\
63 * 927 = 58401\\
78 * 345 = 26910 \\
$$
Without leading zeros, the number of possible combinations decreased.
$$
27 * 594 = 16038\\
36 * 495 = 17820\\
39 * 402 = 15678\\
45 * 396 = 17820\\
46 * 715 = 32890\\
52 * 367 = 19084\\
54 * 297 = 16038\\
63 * 927 = 58401\\
78 * 345 = 26910\\
$$
Hope this can be used to reach the answer.
